# Finding upper segments of intersecting parabolas

Tags: geometry, algorithms, conic-sections

I have multiple parabolas ($y = ax^2 + bx + c$) which may intersect with each other (or some of them may not intersect). I am trying to find upper segments of these parabolas, e.g. bold part in the picture:

[image: intersecting parabolas]

I need to find it in $O(n\log n)$. There's a solution for line version of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420193/how-to-find-upper-envelopes-of-intersected-lines-in-onlogn

But I cannot find a way to apply this solution to quadratic version since there are $a$, $b$ and $c$ variables to consider. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A preliminary transformation you can do to your parabolas is to "complete the square" so they all look like $a(x+d)^2+f$, and then you can sort them from left to right...

Comment: @J.M.: That's only part of it. Parabola $B$ in the diagram might be wider than parabola $A$, so that it breaks out to the left of $A$ although its $d$ parameter is smaller. (Yes, smaller -- perhaps $a(x-d)^2+f$ would be a better parameterisation.)

Comment: @Tony: Yeah, I thought of the "wide parabola" case after commenting; at the very least, the "completed square" form, I think, is more convenient for further manipulations anyway. (Your parametrization is indeed better.)

Comment: After the sort by increasing $d_n$, the n-th parabola $p_n = a_n(x-d_n)^2 + f_n$ can cross all parabolas $1, ..,n-1$, giving an $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: Is coefficient $a$ negative for every parabola?

Comment: In any case, the leftmost and rightmost upper segments will belong to the parabola with the largest value of $a$, not $d$...

Answer (score 7):

You are seeking what is called in the literature *the upper envelope* of a collection of $x$-monotone curves.  Actually, searching for "lower envelope" will give you more hits; obviously they are equivalent.  You might look at the [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) implementation, e.g., via [this link](http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/internal-projects/lower-envelopes-of-planar-curves):

[image: lower envelopes of parabolas]

**Update.** To address joriki's comment, let me quote Theorem 6.5 (p. 137) from the Sharir-Agarwal book, *Davenport-Schinzel Sequences and Their Geometric Applications*:

> Given a collection $\Gamma$ of $n$ $x$-monotone Jordan arcs, each pair of which intersect in at most $s$ points, the lower envelope of $\Gamma$ can be computed in $O(\lambda_{s+1}(n) \log n)$ time.

Because $s=2$ in the case of parabolas, the relevant term is $\lambda_3(n)$.
This $\lambda$-function is a combinatorial quantity that has been proved to
have certain bounds.  A tight bound is known for $\lambda_3(n)$: it is $\Theta( n \alpha(n) )$, where $\alpha(n)$ is the inverse of Ackermann's function, i.e. $\le 5$ in this universe. So the complexity in the theorem is just a hair above $O( n \log n)$.

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest that this would take $O(n\log n)$ time. [The manual](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Envelope_2/Chapter_main.html) says that they use a divide-and-conquer approach in which they split the set of curves into two disjoint subsets. I don't see how this could be done generically in $O(n\log n)$ time for arbitrary curves, without using the specific properties of the parabolas.

Comment: @joriki: Let me update my answer with a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In fact [the result for curves](http://books.google.com/books?id=HSZhIHxHXJAC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA135#v=onepage&q&f=false) (rather than arcs) is even better, with $\lambda_s(n)$ instead of $\lambda_{s+1}(n)$, and $\lambda_2(n)=2n-1\in O(n)$, so the complexity is $O(n\log n)$ in  all universes :-). The $O(n\log n)$ complexity of the divide-and-conquer algorithm also follows from my answer, since the recurrence for it (on the same page) is entirely determined by the number of segments in the envelope, which is $O(n)$ by the Voronoi argument.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks, you are correct re curves vs. arcs!

Answer (score 1):

[*Note: The first version of this answer was incorrect; the comments refer to the incorrect version.*]

I'll assume that the parabolas all open downward as in the diagram; if they don't, things might be more complicated. I'll take $y$ to increase downward to simplify things.

A parabola is the locus of points at equal distance from a point (the focus) and a line (the directrix). In the present case, all directrices are horizontal. If we weight the distance from the focus by adding the $y$ coordinate of the directrix, we can regard the parabola as the locus of points where this weighted distance from the focus is equal to the $y$ coordinate of the point. Above the parabola, the weighted distance from the focus is greater, and below the parabola, the $y$ coordinate is greater. For a point on the upper envelope, the weighted distance from the focus of the parabola forming the envelope is equal to the $y$ coordinate of the point, and the weighted distances from all other foci are less than or equal to this $y$ coordinate. Thus, if we form the additively [weighted Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Voronoi_diagram) of the foci, the parabolic segments forming the upper envelope lie in the Voronoi regions of the corresponding foci.

It follows that the intersections at which the upper envelope switches from one parabola to another lie on edges of the weighted Voronoi diagram. The weighted Voronoi diagram can be computed in $O(n\log n)$ time, for instance using [Fortune's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune%27s_algorithm); the modification for the additively weighted case is straightforward and is described in [the original paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=10549) (Section 4). Since the weighted Voronoi diagram is a planar graph with minimal vertex degree $3$ and $n$ faces, [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs) implies that it has $O(n)$ edges. Thus, the upper envelope can be constructed in $O(n\log n)$ time by computing the weighted Voronoi diagram, finding the intersections of parabolas whose Voronoi regions share an edge, ordering the intersections according to their $x$ coordinates and traversing them from left to right to determine at which of them the envelope switches to a different parabola.

Also see [these notes](http://www.skynet.ie/~sos/mapviewer/docs/Voronoi_Diagram_Notes_1.pdf) for a discussion of the relationship between the upper/lower envelope of a set of parabolas and a Voronoi diagram.

Comment: "Then the parabola is the locus of points equidistant from the directrix and the focus." That can't be right! Why should this parabola coincide with the parabola you started with, when all we know is that they have the same maximum? Even if all parabolas had the same coefficient $a$, it wouldn't be right.

Comment: Just to convince you: "Therefore the intersections of two parabolas lie on the line equidistant between their foci." Take the two parabolas $y=-x^2$, with focus $(0,-1/4)$; and $y = -(x-10)^2+100$, with focus $(10,99\frac{3}{4})$. Yet they meet at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @TonyK: You're quite right, that was quite wrong. I wonder whether any of it can be salvaged for a solution...

Comment: @TonyK: I hope I've fixed it now?

Comment: I don't know! But at least you've made it complicated enough that I can't dismiss it out of hand :-)